# How do I interpret the results of this logistics regression analysis

Tags: logistic

This is the result of a logistic regression analysis, the name of the table is (Logistic regression analysis for the association between different classes and Cardiovascular disease), we think that TYG index is a risk factor for Cardiovascular disease, how do I express the result of this logistic regression analysis or in which ways do I express this result, especially since the adjusted model (model 3) has an OR%95CI containing 1 and the rest of the OR%95CI are greater than 1.[image]

Comment: You seem to be interested in straw-man null hypothesis significance testing without explaining why that is of interest in your setting.   Confidence intervals (better called compatibility intervals) have an interpretation whether or not $H_0$ is true.